# В Android SoundPool метод stop() не работает больше одного раза

Tags: android

В Android `SoundPool` загружен звук. У активности 2 кнопки: "Старт" и "Стоп", вызывающие соответственно методы `soundPool.play(id, 1,1,0,0,1)` и `soundPool.stop(id)`. При старте звук проигрывается, при последующих нажатиях тоже проигрыватеся. Если после любого запуска нажать Стоп, звук остановится. Потом снова можно запустить. Но Стоп после этого уже никогда не срабатывает.

Comment: Проверьте, что вы пытаетесь остановить именно тот стрим, который возвращает метод `play`. Возможно вы сохраняете первый и стопаете всё время его, когда новый `play` вернул уже другой `id`.

Comment: да, все правильно, я сначала в метод stop() передавал идентификатор звука, который получаем при soundpool.load(), а надо передавать целое значение, которое возвращает play()

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что вы передаёте верные id потока в метод `stop`. Туда нужно передавать то значение, которое возвращает ваш метод `soundPool.play`, а не id звука из метода `load`:

```
int id = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.sound, 1); // id звука
int streamId = soundPool.play(id, 1,1,0,0,1);     // id потока
soundPool.stop(streamId);                         // id потока
```